# Git merge issues due to too many PRs and Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

We are following a Git process that is causing problem with merging as mentioned below.

1. PersonA creates branch branchA from master and personB creates branchB from master.
2. When personA's work is done and pushed to branchA, jenkins pipeline gets triggered which takes 30 mins to complete. Now, when PR is approved , he doesn't merge and do some other work.
3. Now, PersonB's work is done and he is running and pipeline and raised the PR to merge into master.
4. If PersonA merges his code to master now, the pipeline that was run by PersonB is becoming obsolete as he has to to take updates from master and commit again.
5. This triggers another round of jenkins pipeline and only after it's completion can personB merge code into master.

Is there any Git Flow, that can avoid this?

Comment: In the same situation, except in 1 we have person A .. person Z, and in 4, person B .. person Z's work is becoming obsolete. The merge manager uses extreme caution and sometimes merges outdated PRs.